# document.createElement Performance: Edge/IE11 too slow v/s Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Some of the web portals that I maintain use `document.createElement` to create `options` in a `dropdownlist` at runtime. All was well till IE10 but in `IE11` or `Edge` suddenly the performance has gone down dramatically.

I have created a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nitinph/ej5p65um/

Please run it using both the sets of browsers (IE11/Edge and Chrome/Firefox). You will notice that IE11/Edge takes 10+ seconds whereas Chrome/Firefox takes less than a second.

My question is that is there any alternate way for using `document.createElement` so that performance is similar in IE11/Edge.

```js
var pTime = document.getElementById("pTime");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
var ddl = document.getElementById("TestDDL");
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.text = i;
  opt.value = i;
  ddl.options.add(opt);
}
d = new Date();
var n1 = d.getTime();
pTime.innerHTML = 'Time: ' + (n1 - n) / 1000 + ' sec.';
```

```html
<select id="TestDDL">
</select>
<p id="pTime">
</p>
```

**Update**: Courtesy **@Squint**, here are the four alternatives to achieve performance in IE11/Edge:

```js
var ddl = document.getElementById("TestDDL");

console.time("html")
var s = ""
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  s += "<option value='" + i + '>' + i + "</option>"
}
ddl.innerHTML = s;
console.timeEnd("html")

clearContent()

console.time("insertAdjacentHTML")
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
 ddl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<option value='" + i + '>' + i + "</option>")
}
console.timeEnd("insertAdjacentHTML")

clearContent()

console.time("frag")
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.text = i;
  opt.value = i;
  frag.appendChild(opt);
}
ddl.appendChild(frag);
console.timeEnd("frag")

clearContent()

console.time("direct add")
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.text = i;
  opt.value = i;
  ddl.options.add(opt);
}
console.timeEnd("direct add")


function clearContent() {
 while (ddl.firstChild) {
   ddl.removeChild(ddl.firstChild)
  }
}

clearContent()

console.time("direct append")
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.text = i;
  opt.value = i;
  ddl.appendChild(opt);
}
console.timeEnd("direct append")


function clearContent() {
 while (ddl.firstChild) {
   ddl.removeChild(ddl.firstChild)
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="TestDDL">
</select>
<p id="pTime">
</p>
```

Comment: Please put all relevant code directly in the question instead of just linking to it on some other site.

Comment: Is this issue specific to `option` elements? Or to using the `.add()` method? Have you tried appending to a `documentFragment` in the loop, then appending that to the `select` element?

Comment: @squint: This issue is specific to `document.createElement`. The marked answer below hits the bulls-eye.

Comment: You sure about that? Because if I use `document.createElement()` but append to a fragment, I get *far* better performance in IE11. Not as good as `.innerHTML`, but still a massive improvement. So it doesn't seem to be specific to `document.createElement()` at all. And with `.innerHTML`, you open yourself up to XSS attacks if the source isn't secure. This is why I asked.

Comment: @NP3 This has nothing to do with `document.createElement`, it's `options.add()` slowing down your code. See [a fiddle using `appendChild`](https://jsfiddle.net/wqbxua2c/).

Comment: @Teemu: Looks like you are right. Can you post it as answer? I will mark it as answer.

Comment: @squint: Your guess is right but since I am not an expert in JavaScript I was expecting an answer so I could not go ahead with your suggestions.

Comment: And I was expecting a response to my questions. Anyway, here's a comparison of 5 different ways (including yours). https://jsfiddle.net/8ax5LLv2/1/ Take whichever one you prefer (if any), and put it in an answer if you want.

Comment: @squint: there you go, I have posted the updated snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct the element HTML with strings:

```
var optionList = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var elementHTML = "";

for (var index = 0; index < optionList.length; index++) {
    elementHTML += "<option>" + optionList[index] + "</option>";
}
```

Then create the element and set the innerHTML

```
var element = document.createElement("select");
element.innerHTML = elementHTML;
```

This usually offers much better performance as you only call `document.createElement()` once. Direct dynamic DOM processing, sadly, is usually pretty slow and is recommended against.

Comment: I am upvoting you since this is also solving my problem. But `.appendChild` seems to be a better solution.